# The complement of the poles of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Why does the complement of the set of poles of a meromorphic function form a connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Angelic answer:** because the complement of a closed discrete subset of $\mathbb C$ is connected.

**Diabolical answer:** because the complement of a denumerable subset  $D\subset \mathbb C$ is path-connected.
**Proof:**    Take $a,b\notin D$ and consider all arcs of circle joining $a$ to $b$.
There are a continuum of them  but only denumerably many contain a point of $D$.
 So any other arc is a path entirely contained in the complement of $D$ and joining $a$ to $b$  .

Comment: One could add, to be even more diabolical : The complement in $\mathbb{C}$ of a totally disconnected compact set is connected. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55718/complement-of-a-totally-disconnected-closed-set-in-the-plane

Comment: Dear @Malik, if the totally disconnected set has to be compact, your result is differently diabolical, but not more diabolical! However according to your link, it seems that compactness is actually not required.

Comment: Dear Georges : Yes you are right. I also think one does not need compactness.

Answer (score 1):

Meromorphic implies that the poles of a function are isolated points. And $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$, for $S$ a set of isolated points, is connected (even more, it is path connected, as should be easy to see).